# Creating multicolumn list-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I wanted to create multicolumn list-group to have different number of columns in different resolutions using Bootstrap (newest version 3.2.0).

I used the following code to achieve this:

```
<div class="list-group col-lg-12">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
    <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">My title</h2>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
  <a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
<a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
<a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
<a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
<a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
<a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
<a href="" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge alert-info ">0</span> item1</a>
  </div>       
</div>
```

and it works exactly as I wanted - [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/ku9DpJp3wf)

However using such solution caused one problem. When I want to display anything later, for example:

```
<p class="clearfix alert alert-warning text-center">
 a piece of code
</p>
```

it seems there is a problem with clearing floats what can be seen here: [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/jl2r7EKxtR)

**Question** - can it be easily fixed or maybe I cannot put extra divs when using `list-group`? I tried to use `clearfix` but without any success. If it cannot be fixed is there any other solution to achieve the same result using Boostrap? I was looking in other components but haven't found anything other and obviously I don't want to use tables for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap `<div class="list-group col-lg-12">` with `<div class="row">` and the clearfix works then.
All your col-md style tags should be in a div class row or alike (controls-row could also be used). Rows should also be inside a container. 
Example here: http://www.bootply.com/azBEpNdMZq
More info here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Ah yes, well noticed. This is only needed when using floated elements (pull-left and pull-right).

Comment: There is one problem with that solution. If you look at http://www.bootply.com/yFM4p51NJ7 (I've change some things) you will see that adding rows inside list-group will cause that when you open it as mobile you will get horizontal scrollbar when resizing your browser to minimum. And removing it will cause list-group won't take full container width - http://www.bootply.com/64aKo3Rtcc

Comment: A few people have been reporting this issue in recent versions of Bootstrap. 
I found a fix\ workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392477/how-to-make-bootstrap-3-fluid-layout-without-horizontal-scrollbar
Adding `body { overflow-x: hidden;}` to your css will resolve this issue-  http://www.bootply.com/BV7NpHyw1e

Comment: I saw this but I thought it's related to fluid container and rather earlier versions of Bootstrap.