# Bootstrap .container > .row horizontal scroll issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I've already taken a look into these solutions (same problem):

1. [Stackoverflow Question 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392477/how-to-make-bootstrap-3-fluid-layout-without-horizontal-scrollbar)
2. [GitHub problem 2013](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8959)

But none , seem to work for me apart from the ugly hack of

```
body { overflow-x: hidden;}
```

I just downloaded the current bootstrap distribution from their website (v3.3.4).It also has this `.container-fluid`class which is supposed to be the fix for this problem. However, I'm still having this issue and wanted to know if others have also faced this problem. I'm getting this issue in localhost ( using MAMP ). I haven't tried production server yet as I'm confused about why this problem still persists. I decided to post this question as the previous issues were raised a couple of years ago.

My code setup is an extremely basic one (I've used `container` class too) :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 column">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 column">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 column">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle?

Comment: We need the code for your `column` class. It might be breaking things. Also, try [Bootlinting](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify the bootstrap `CSS` too:

```
.row{ margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}

.container{
    .row{margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;}
}
```

And try.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this while having issues with another bootstrap trick, I understand it's old but thought I'd answer it for those in the future.

The problem is that you are using row AFTER the container.

If you're trying to nest rows, you're doing it incorrectly but from your code that's not how it appears. If you are just trying to get your screen to be at 100% width all you need to do is move your `.row` above `.container-fluid`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 column">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 column">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 column">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Although this question is a little vague this should fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the above didn't help...

I just put: `overflow: hidden` to the parent div of all my containers and worked perfectly.

In my case the parent div was `<div class="hfeed site" id="page">`