# How do I make this div span the entire width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have already included this:

```
<style>
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
}
</style>
```

And below is my code for the div I am referring to including its content:

```
<div class="learn-more">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 style="color: #292f33;">SERVICES</h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Delivery</h4><hr style="max-width: 70px;">
      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 19px; font-family: Segoe UI;">At Gadget Market we offer free delivery for purchases prized over $300. Our delivery service is up to your doorstep or wherever you would like within the country.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Warranty</h4><hr style="max-width: 70px;">
      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 19px; font-family: Segoe UI;">Devices from Gadget Market come with not less than a 12-month warranty. Gadget issues within this period will be catered for and a replacement provided if need be.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Money back Guarantee</h4><hr style="max-width: 70px;">
      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 19px; font-family: Segoe UI;">If you are not satisfied with the product you bought from Gadget market, then you can return the gadget to us within 30 days for a 90% money back guarantee.</p>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.learn-more {
  background-size: cover;
  width: inherit; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  background-color: rgba(85,172,238,0.8); 
}

.learn-more .col-md-4 h4 {
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #292f33;
}

.learn-more .col-md-4 p {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #292f33;
}
```

However the div `.learn-more` still doesn't span the entire width. And I find this to be weird because I used the exact same code on another project and it worked!

And the link below is the image:

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYdcR.png)

Comment: Which `div` are you referring to, explicitly?

Comment: Hi there - can you help us which div is "the div"?  You've got about 6 divs in the markup above.   Additionally, can you advise the other styles, particularly for `div.learn-more` and `div.container`?

Comment: I am referring to the .learn-more div

Answer (score 2):

This is a Bootstrap matter. Change this

```
<div class="container">
```

to this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

And *(to prevent a horizontal scrollbar)* change the `<div class="learn-more">` into a `<section class="learn-more">`, as per this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35236594/1447509

---

Note that typical Bootstrap scaffolding looks like this:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    //content
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    //content col 2
                </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    //content
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    //content col 2
                </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- .container -->
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a known bootstrap situation. Keep playing around with this - I'm betting your problem is related to it. Try adjusting your HTML structure to be more like the scaffolding I just added to my updated answer.

Comment: What's pissing me off is the fact that on a different website project, it works perfectly!

Comment: Is that common too? With no alterations or anything...it works!

Comment: Are you saying that it is working now, or still having trouble? If still trouble, try reproducing the problem on [bootply](http://bootply.com) and post the link. We'll keep trying to help you fix it.

Comment: You can also try changing `<div class="row">` to `<div class="row-fluid">`. Worth a shot...

Comment: I meant it hasn't worked yet. I have the code on pastebin, is that okay? Can I share that link?

Comment: Yes, share the link, but add it to your original question also so that others can also see it easily.

Comment: [link] (pastebin.com/A4LkJQ26

Comment: One of the divs wasn't terminated, Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 1):

Make a style code for the div that sets the width at 100%

```
.learn-more {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It appears like your div is inheriting its width from the parent element. What element is the parent of the div, and what styles does it have?

Comment: Oh sorry, no it isn't. That was supposed to be 'width: 100%;' and I have changed it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
.learn-more,.learn-more .container{
  width : 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your codes online and give me the link. I will solve in 1 minute.

Comment: One of the divs wasn't terminated. Thanks a lot though

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to give enough time to the problem, but very happy to hear you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the inherit characteristic. `width: inherit` gives 100% of the parent. Not the whole document. To ignore the typical restrictions on width being more than the parent, do the below.

```
.learn-more{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to put this as an answer, unless if works, but remove the h1, and if that doesn't work remove all the children of learn-more, at least this way we know where the problem is. If one works, tell me and I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `!important` for `padding` and `margin` to the selector `html, body` like this:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
```

As in your screenshot, I can see scrollbar is at the bottom so you are having more divs on top and probably more CSS, so if something is changing padding and margin value then it gets corrected now. You should also check if your divs are closing properly and don't have any unclosed div prior to your code, then try adding `overflow:hidden` to `.learn-more`.

Comment: Rakesh, you must have seen wrong. I do not have a scrollbar at the bottom

Comment: One of the divs had not been terminated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i said it wrong, your vertical scrollbar was scrolled to bottom. I didn't mean there is horizontal scrollbar at bottom. Glad it helped!