# Bootstrap - Make grid system not adjust with or without scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap grid system to dynamically layout contents on my page. However, the width of the fluid layout shifts when a scrollbar appears making it a little jarring to look at.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make bootstrap 3 fluid layout without horizontal scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392477/how-to-make-bootstrap-3-fluid-layout-without-horizontal-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know how many grid do you want in your dynamic content?

Let me explain, if you want to 3 grids in your dynamic content then put your loop in div which have class row,and make sure that your div with class row is in container or container fluid.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        /* your loop code goes here with grid class */ 
        <div class="col-md-3"> /*whenever you loop work then this div will repeat*/
           your content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```